# delete min. values from records after comparing two values from table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to filter data from table: `tbl_entso_cdbf`.
The table has trade information from one area to other area:

```
  Utc             |      date         |area_in|area_out|  value  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00:00| 275   |  40    |   320   |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00:00| 40    |  275   |   0     |
2015-12-06T03:00Z |2015-12-06 03:00:00| 100   |  175   |   550   |
2015-12-06T03:00Z |2015-12-06 03:00:00| 175   |  100   |   0     |
2015-11-04T03:00Z |2015-11-04 03:00:00| 280   |  310   |   0     |
2015-11-04T03:00Z |2015-11-04 03:00:00| 310   |  280   |   0     |
2016-09-19T00:00Z |2016-09-19 00:00:00| 187   |  292   |   45    |
2016-09-19T00:00Z |2016-09-19 00:00:00| 292   |  187   |   0     |
```

Table contains export and import values between `area_in` and `area_out`.
This table contains double entries in value column refere to `date` column.For ex., first two rows have same date and time `2015-12-05 03:00:00` but two different values `320` and `0`. I want to have only one value `320` and delete second row which has `0` value. It means trade between area_in `275` and area_out `40` at same date and time `2015-12-05 03:00:00` should have unique positive value. Same implies for row no. 3, 4, 7 and 8.
But in rows 5 and 6 both have `0` values so I want to have only  one record (any one of them).

So, in the end I want my table to be looked like:

```
Utc               |      date         |area_in|area_out|  value  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00:00| 275   |  40    |   320   |
2015-12-06T03:00Z |2015-12-06 03:00:00| 100   |  175   |   550   |
2015-11-04T03:00Z |2015-11-04 03:00:00| 310   |  280   |   0     |
2016-09-19T00:00Z |2016-09-19 00:00:00| 187   |  292   |   45    |
```

This table has millions of such kind of rows to filter. can any one help me to write a sql query ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: And what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Do you want to get the greater value (320) an delete the minor value (>320 (value1)) or do you want to sum both rows and then delete the duplicate rows?

Comment: Or third option: Do you want to keep the greater value and delete the minor (or zero) value, without summing up both values?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I haven't set any primary key to table because when I try to set primary key to any of columns, it shows me error of duplicate entry.

Comment: Hi flxplzk, I want greater value of them like 320 and delete the entire row with value of 0. But if both values are zero then at least one entry must be there for sake of record (it doesn't matter which entry).

Comment: okay i will try to create a query, but i am struggeling an auto generated primary key would have been great to solve this much easier

Comment: hi flxplzk, actually I had set primary keys for every column except date column before but I don't know how the size of database increases tremendously and causes database operation inactive mode. So, I removed all primary keys and its easy to perform operation than before.

Comment: What if I have set primary keys as given below: 
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_entsoe_cbeflows` (
 `utc` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `area_in` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `area_out` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `value` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`utc`, `area_in`, `area_out`, `value`)
)

Comment: Until you have a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table.

Comment: Yes I have primary keys for these columns PRIMARY KEY (`utc`, `area_in`, `area_out`, `value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the rows you want to delete with this query:

```
select t0.* 
from tbl_entso_cdbf t0
join tbl_entso_cdbf t1
  on  t1.Utc  = t0.Utc
  and t1.date = t0.date
  and t1.area_in  = t0.area_out
  and t1.area_out = t0.area_in
where t0.value = 0
  and (t1.value <> 0 or t1.area_in < t0.area_in);
```

The conditions are:

- `value = 0`
- There is another row with same `Utc` and same `date` but `area_in` and `area_out` are switched.
- The `value` of the other row is not `0` **or** `area_in` is smaller.

The query will return the follwing rows:

```
|               Utc |                date | area_in | area_out | value |
|-------------------|---------------------|---------|----------|-------|
| 2015-12-05T03:00Z | 2015-12-05 03:00:00 |      40 |      275 |     0 |
| 2015-12-06T03:00Z | 2015-12-06 03:00:00 |     175 |      100 |     0 |
| 2015-11-04T03:00Z | 2015-11-04 03:00:00 |     310 |      280 |     0 |
| 2016-09-19T00:00Z | 2016-09-19 00:00:00 |     292 |      187 |     0 |
```

Now use it in a subquery of the delete statement:

```
delete t1
from tbl_entso_cdbf t1
natural join (
    select t0.*
    from tbl_entso_cdbf t0
    join tbl_entso_cdbf t1
      on  t1.Utc  = t0.Utc
      and t1.date = t0.date
      and t1.area_in  = t0.area_out
      and t1.area_out = t0.area_in
    where t0.value = 0
      and (t1.value <> 0 or t1.area_in < t0.area_in)    
) t0;
```

`NATURAL JOIN` means that all column values must be equal. If you had a primary (or any unique) key, you would only need to select the primary (unique) key columns in the subquery instead of `*`.

Now only the following rows are left in the table:

```
|               Utc |                date | area_in | area_out | value |
|-------------------|---------------------|---------|----------|-------|
| 2015-12-05T03:00Z | 2015-12-05 03:00:00 |     275 |       40 |   320 |
| 2015-12-06T03:00Z | 2015-12-06 03:00:00 |     100 |      175 |   550 |
| 2015-11-04T03:00Z | 2015-11-04 03:00:00 |     280 |      310 |     0 |
| 2016-09-19T00:00Z | 2016-09-19 00:00:00 |     187 |      292 |    45 |
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! I performed this query  It works absolutely fine on my small table but when I use in my main table it hangs the process because of large number of rows. So, I am thinking on other solution that, I will extract those rows from raw data table,  excluding the rows which I want to delete afterwards especially containing `0`, instead extracting all data and perform this delete operation. Thanks once again, your soulution was exact what  I wanted. I will use your query for my next solution.

Comment: @mitedu Try an index on `(Utc, date, area_in, area_out)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your table with primary key looks something like this:

```
      pk |   Utc             |      date         |area_in|area_out|  value  | 
      -----------------------------------------------------------------------
       1 | 2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00:00| 275   |  40    |   320   |
       2 | 2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00:00| 40    |  275   |   0     |
       3 | 2015-12-06T03:00Z |2015-12-06 03:00:00| 100   |  175   |   550   |
       4 | 2015-12-06T03:00Z |2015-12-06 03:00:00| 175   |  100   |   0     |
       5 | 2015-11-04T03:00Z |2015-11-04 03:00:00| 280   |  310   |   0     |
       6 | 2015-11-04T03:00Z |2015-11-04 03:00:00| 310   |  280   |   0     |
       7 | 2016-09-19T00:00Z |2016-09-19 00:00:00| 187   |  292   |   45    |
       8 | 2016-09-19T00:00Z |2016-09-19 00:00:00| 292   |  187   |   0     |
```

With execution this query you should be able to delete the rows you want to get rid of:

```
 DELETE FROM  tbl_entso_cdbf
 WHERE pk IN (SELECT PK_DEL
             FROM (Select   pk AS PK_DEL
                          , utc
                          , value
                          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY utc ORDER BY value desc) AS DUB_IND
                   FROM tbl_entso_cdbf 
                   WHERE DUB_IND <> 1
                   )
             );
```

That query is suposed to delete all rows where the pk in in the return of the subquery. The subquery shall return all primary keys of the records, where the value is minor as the duplicates. But please, before trying this make shure, that this query returns the wanted result of records that should be deleted:

```
Select   pk AS PK_DEL
       , utc
       , value
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY utc ORDER BY value desc) AS DUB_IND
FROM tbl_entso_cdbf 
WHERE DUB_IND <> 1
```

If so, you should be able to delete the duplicates!

Comment: thanks for your inputs, I checked your query but shows some error `server version for right syntax to use near '(partition by utc ORDER BY value desc)` I have gone through some other solutions but couldn't trace out where it goes wrong. [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1). I checked for reserverd keywords also.